# Need to avoid Matrix format output on my sql and bring repeated row in to single row

Tags: mysql

Based on some calculation i have got like below out(current output) on Mysql, but i want display expected output.

```
Current Output                                      
Id  Line    L1_C    L1_D    L1_E    L2_F    L2_G    L2_H    L3_I    L3_J    L3_K
1   1       test    tets    tes     null    null    null    null    null    null
1   2       null    null    null    test    etst    etts    null    null    null            
1   3       null    null    null    null    null    null    fgdf    dfgf    fdg



Expected Output                                     
Id  Line    L1_C    L1_D    L1_E    L2_F    L2_G    L2_H    L3_I    L3_J    L3_K
1   1       test    tets    tes     test    etst    etts    fgdf    dfgf    fdg
```

Thank you!

Comment: please show details about table and what you tried in query.

Comment: Please consider current output as a table and have to convert into expected output as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check This One

```
select ID,Line,max(L1_C),max(L1_D),max(L1_E),max(L2_F),max(L2_G),max(L2_H),
max(L3_I),max(L3_J),max(L3_K)
from your_table
group by ID
```

we have used `group by ID` - it will group records based on `ID` and take all data as group like this

```
1   1       test    tets    tes     null    null    null    null    null    null
1   2       null    null    null    test    etst    etts    null    null    null            
1   3       null    null    null    null    null    null    fgdf    dfgf    fdg
```

after that we used max so from these three row it will tax max value(i.e.in `L1_C` records are test,null,null so max is test) hence for other columns also  it will check data of max(three rows).

Comment: Thank you so much MJ, This gives expected output.

Comment: MJ, Please explain how this MAX function is working, this helps me to get good understanding of the MAX function..